# Nuxt Middleware: Manual refresh of page causes Vuex store property to be "null" -- how to fix?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

I've got an app that uses middleware to try and redirect a user to another page if he is not logged in.

The page that uses it is set up like so:

`pages/upload.vue`:

```
export default {
  name: 'Upload',
  middleware: 'redirect',
  ...etc...
```

The `middleware/redirect.js` file looks like so:

```
export default function ({ redirect, store }) {
  const isLoggedIn = store.getters.isLoggedIn
  console.log(isLoggedIn)
  // if (!isLoggedIn) {
  //   redirect({ name: 'login' })
  // }
}
```

Navigating TO the `upload` page works fine and the console is logged with `true` from the middleware, however, doing a manual page refresh or typing the page upload URL in the browser causes the `console.log(isLoggedIn)` to output `false`.

So, here is my `store/getters.js` file logic:

```
export default {
  isLoggedIn: (state) => {
    try {
      return state.userProfile.uid !== null
    } catch {
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

`store/state.js` is like so:

```
export default () => ({
    authUser: null,
    userProfile: null
  })
```

It looks like the user state is null on initial SSR load. I am using a custom plugin called `auth` like so:

`plugins/auth.js`:
and loaded it in `nuxt.config.js` like so:

```
plugins: [
{ src: '~/plugins/auth.js' }
]
```

```
import { onAuthStateChanged, getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { doc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { db } from '~/plugins/firebase'

export default (context, inject) => {
  const auth = getAuth()
  inject(
    'authObserver',
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
      console.log('user state:', user)
      if (user) {
      ...etc...
}
```

So, all together, the above code outputs the following console log (note the `null` user state on SSR!):

[image]

**OK, so obviously we should not care about SSR for client logic like this as it's not needed for crawlers, so how should I write the logic for the middleware to check whether a user is logged in or not? That way I can redirect him to login page to login before proceeding to upload page.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [Firebase Session Cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies#create_session_cookie) if you need user's information before rendering the web page in SSR. You can then check for the cookie in your middleware, if it's present then you can verify it using [`verifySessionCookie`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies#verify_session_cookie_and_check_permissions) method (similar to `verifyIdToken`) in Admin SDK.

If the cookie is valid then add user info to state and render the page else redirect to login or any other page.

I recently wrote an answer explaining how to get user data on server side in short here:

[Next.js Get user data in SSR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69242671/next-js-get-user-data-in-ssr/69242711#69242711)