Determine Firebase Authentication user in NextJS middleware
// src/middleware.ts

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"
import { auth } from '@/lib/firebase/firebase'

const estaLogado: boolean = true

export const middleware = async (request: NextRequest) => {

    console.log(auth.currentUser)

    if (estaLogado) {
        return NextResponse.next()
    }

    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", request.url))
}

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/', '/horario', '/materias', '/notas']
}

Middleware file in NextJS
//src/lib/firebase/firebase.js

import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID
};

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);`your text`
export const auth = getAuth(app)
export const db = getFirestore(app)

Importing from my firebase app
Why the console.log() in the middleware file is returning null if I actualy have an user authenticated?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69242671/next-js-get-user-data-in-ssr?
